# Multiple Ember Apps in one Yeoman Ember project

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, grunt-ember-templates

Is it possible have multiple apps that share UI/CSS/libs etc. in one yeoman ember project with one Gruntfile.js?

I have tried using the Yeoman ember generator, and it is wonderful for 1 app environment at a time.

But my situation is that I have multiple ember apps (that are required to be separate because of work oriented restrictions) that all use the same UI (LESS/CSS, bower_components).

So, instead of having to initiate 5 different build environments (Yeoman ember generators) that duplicate the same UI elements, I would love to be able to have them all in one build environment instead. I have tried building the taxonomy and tweaking the grunt tasks but it seems that the Ember compiling logic for the 'generator-ember' only looks at the index.html in the root.

Any info/insight is welcome.